In package mcexam answer key table doesn't fit in page
In a test with randomized questions and many versions, the answer key table comes out of the margins and the program does not automatically add another page (see picture 1). In my case I have 20 multiple choice questions and a 18 versions of the test. I could possibly fit in landscape mode but I am wondering if it is possible to split the answer key table in multiple pages.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[output=key
           ,numberofversions=18
           ,version=1
           ,seed=1
           ,randomizequestions=true
           ,randomizeanswers=true
           ,writeRfile=true
           ]{mcexam}
    


It is nice to see a picture, but without code segments and an understandable description it is just left to saying "nice picture".

You are right Leucippus, I'll provide a better description of the issue
